# K-Means on age and weight

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I have applied K-Means on a problem where I have random dateset of age and weight, after applying K means, I still cannot understand that why data points are not converging to centroids.

```
age = [20,21,22,20,21,22,23,27,28,26,23,28,29,33,28,25,24,28,29,30,33,31,40,22,28,29,27,25,29,23]
weight = [80,50,70,50,82,49,60,66,76,45,66,86,77,56,76,81,72,92,72,91,72,75,60,61,99,54,56,45,40,76]

df_main = pd.DataFrame({'age':age_array,'weight':weight_array})

X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)

# Run local implementation of kmeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, max_iter=100)

km.fit(X_std)
centroids = km.cluster_centers_
# Plot the clustered data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

plt.scatter(X_std[km.labels_ == 0, 0], X_std[km.labels_ == 0, 1],
            c='green', label='cluster 1')

plt.scatter(X_std[km.labels_ == 1, 0], X_std[km.labels_ == 1, 1],
            c='blue', label='cluster 2')

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='*', s=50,
            c='red', label='centroid')

plt.legend()

plt.xlim([-2, 2])

plt.ylim([-2, 2])

plt.xlabel('Age')

plt.ylabel('Height')

plt.title('Visualization of clustered data', fontweight='bold')
```

[image: chart]

Comment: What do you mean by "data points are not converging to centroids"? Data points are static, they can't converge to anything

Comment: I am not able to differentiate like which point goes to cluster one and which goes to cluster two, as both are merged.
Shouldn't they be like some line which shows that above points are of cluster one and the lower is of cluster two?
Sorry If I am wrong, I am new to this. @ForceBru

Comment: One cluster is blue, and the other is green - they don't look merged to me. If you're using scikit-learn, `km.labels_` is exactly the way to classify points, and it looks like you're doing this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't fully understand [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

What actually is happening that every iteration the centroids are recalculated to minimize the distance between them and the data points. (in the first iteration they are selected randomly or by other initialization).

When the process is ended we recalculate for each data point the distance from it to the centroids and the min distance will determine which set this data point is part of.
Therefore the centroids will usually not converge to any data point, actually if that happens it is a sign that your hyperparams can be optimized (decrease k for instance).

Comment: Yes, my concept was weak. I read about it, so I started implementing, guess I need to study more. :), thanks though.